# How can we use the examples in a scenario outline for test data generation in another scenario

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I have used specflow and This is an enrollment feature where basic details are entered for enrollment in the enrollment form.
The flow is as below.
After enrollment, the patient and the details filled in the enrollment is added to the application. Once enrolled, admin can open the profile of the enrolled patient and perform actions in profile.

[Enrollment.Feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGCCa.png)

Didnt try anything as I have no idea if we will be able to use the same variable values passed in examples in a scenario in a different feature file's scenario

Please help

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Copy and paste it as plain text in your question. Use the `{ }` icon to format it as code.

Comment: please don't try and do this. your scenarios should be independent and there is no way to guarantee  that your tests will be run in any particular order, and the order may change at any time, at the behest of the test runner...

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario `Enroll patient from Client Enrollment Page` explicitly lists all data in examples table and that is good, as that may be crucial for the feature it describes/tests.

I understand your itch to reuse something from here in tests of other features. However, when writing BDD scenarios, we should always ask ourselves if we are putting all the important information in the scenario, **and no** ***more***. I imagine that for most scenarios on other features of your application all or some details of enrolled patients may be irrelevant. You may then use a `Given` step that asserts that *some* patients exist in the app, as a precondition.

```
Given enrolled patients exist
```

or

```
Given 10 enrolled patients exist
```

Such steps can take some predefined data set (from an external file, or some project resource, or maybe even embedded in code) and iterate over it, creating patients one by one. Alternatively, they can just change the app's underlying persistant storage eg. UPDATE a table in DB or replace some file.

If you are sure that the feature for which you are writing scenarios requires more specificity in patients' data, you can construct a `Given` step that uses a data table to pass data to the step definition, like this

```
Given following enrolled patients exist
    | FirstName | LastName | DOB   | ... |
    | Sandra    | Alpha    | 31337 | ... |
    | Marie     | Beta     | 12345 | ... |
    | ...       | ...      | ...   | ... |
```

Check documentation on SpecFlow.Assist Helpers that has some nice ways to make your life with step's data tables easier, like creating collection of objects with just one method: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/SpecFlow-Assist-Helpers.html

This apporach is nice because you can reuse this step in many scenarios/features and just change datatable contents depending on needs of the feature you are describing/testing.

Alternatively, you can tag scenarios that require some particular set of patients and then use these tags as conditions in `BeforeScenario` hook, to populate the DB (or whatever) with a specific patient dataset even before the scenarios itself starts. Then a `Given` step similar to the ones before can still can be used, but its definition is just an assertion. Sometimes you even should do that, to ensure that someone reading the scenario understands the setup/precondition (remember: BDD scenarios are for describing the feature, the fact that they can be executed as tests is like a nice by-product).

You can use a `Given` step similar to the ones above in each scenario that needs it, or put it in a `Background` of a feature file.

Related reading: https://specflow.org/gherkin/outlines-background-or-hooks/